# Help on composition of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, function-and-relation-composition

I know how to compose normal functions but never seen this type of task any help?

> Find the composition $g \circ f$ of the following functions $f, g : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ given by the formulas:
>   $$\begin{align*}
> f(x) &= \begin{cases} x^2 + 1 & \text{if } x \in (-\infty, 0) \\ x - 2 & \text{if } x \in [0, +\infty) \end{cases} \\
> g(x) &= \begin{cases} x + 2 & \text{if } x \in (-\infty, 2) \\ 1 - 2x^2 & \text{if } x \in [2, +\infty) \end{cases}.
> \end{align*}$$

Comment: You should provide a picture with better quality or rewrite a problem, also show what you have already tried.

Comment: Redefine your functions on 3 intervals :$(-\infty,0)$, $(0,2)$, $(2,\infty)$ and compose your functions over these intervals.

Comment: [link](https://scontent-frt3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/51675133_374967143295397_492830935822106624_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_ht=scontent-frt3-2.xx&oh=75107bab6b9825b897417512cc2315ad&oe=5CED188C) _italic_ **bold** `code` this my attempt and task

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

To calculate $g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)$, you have to determine when $f(x)<2$ and when $f(x)\ge 2$. Consider separately the cases $x<0$ and $x\ge 0$.

Comment: https://scontent-frt3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/51675133_374967143295397_492830935822106624_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_ht=scontent-frt3-2.xx&oh=75107bab6b9825b897417512cc2315ad&oe=5CED188C

Comment: Like in this link?

Comment: Which link${}$?

Comment: https://scontent-frt3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/51675133_374967143295397_492830935822106624_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_ht=scontent-frt3-2.xx&oh=75107bab6b9825b897417512cc2315ad&oe=5CED188C

Comment: No: you need to know where $y=f(x)$ lives, to know why formula to apply for $g(y)